# TFS 2015 add collection level create team project permission for user

Tags: tfs

I am the admin of TFS 2015 Update 3. I would like to allow one power user create team projects permissions on a dedicated collection for his department. what is the best practices for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To create team projects you must have the **[Create new projects permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions#nbspnbspnbspcollection-level)** set to **Allow**.

- If you don't mind the power user have other related collection level
  permissions, the simplest solution is adding him to  **Project
  Collection Administrators Group**. How to do this please follow this
  [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/set-project-collection-level-permissions#add-a-user-or-group-to-a-security-group).
  *Since Project Collection Administrators are granted all collection-level permissions.*
- If you just want to give the power user  create new projects
  permission or not all collection level permissions. Suggest you to crate
  a new collection level "security group", setting the properly
  permission for the group. Finally, add the power user in this group.

And this is for a dedicated collection, unless you explicitly add that power user to another team project collection admin group, otherwise he do not have corresponding permission to create team projects in that collection.

You could manage **collection-level** permissions through [the web portal admin context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/user-guide/work-web-portal#admin-context) or [TFSSecurity command-line tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd#collection-level-permissions).